# Weblogic Unable to deploy EJB javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I have 2 ejb(s), `MyTestEB` in `mytest`  project and `TestEB` in `test` project. `mytest` project references to `test` project

`MyTestEB` in `ejb-jar.xml` file in `mytest` project:

```
<entity id="Entity_TransactionEB">
        <description>Transaction Entity Bean</description>
        <display-name>Transaction Entity Bean</display-name>
        <ejb-name>MyTestEB</ejb-name>
        <local-home>
            test.transaction.ejb.TransactionLocalHome
        </local-home>
        <local>
            test.transaction.ejb.TransactionLocal
        </local>
        <ejb-class>
            test.transaction.ejb.TransactionBean
        </ejb-class>
        <persistence-type>Bean</persistence-type>
        <prim-key-class>
            test.transaction.TransactionKey
        </prim-key-class>
        <reentrant>False</reentrant>
        <resource-ref id="ResourceRef_TransactionEB_jdbc">
            <res-ref-name>jdbc/DataSource</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
    </entity>
```

`test.transaction.ejb.TransactionLocalHome`; `test.transaction.ejb.TransactionBean` and `test.transaction.TransactionKey` are all in `test` project

`TestEB` in `ejb-jar.xml` file in `test` project:

```
<entity id="Entity_TransactionEB">
            <description>Transaction Entity Bean</description>
            <display-name>Transaction Entity Bean</display-name>
            <ejb-name>TestEB</ejb-name>
            <local-home>
                test.transaction.ejb.TransactionLocalHome
            </local-home>
            <local>
                test.transaction.ejb.TransactionLocal
            </local>
            <ejb-class>
                test.transaction.ejb.TransactionBean
            </ejb-class>
            <persistence-type>Bean</persistence-type>
            <prim-key-class>
                test.transaction.TransactionKey
            </prim-key-class>
            <reentrant>False</reentrant>
            <resource-ref id="ResourceRef_TransactionEB_jdbc">
                <res-ref-name>jdbc/DataSource</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
            </resource-ref>
        </entity>
```

When I deploy my application in Weblogic, I got the error(error snippet):

```
Unable to deploy EJB: MyTestEB from mytest-ejb.jar:

[EJB:011072]Unable to bind EJB Local Home Interface to the JNDI name: TestEB.
javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: TestEB is already bound; remaining name ''
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.bindHere(BasicNamingNode.java:357)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"JNDI name is already bound" occurs when there are more that one instance tries to get tied to the JNDI tree. You can check what is causing this by opening the console -> Domain ->  Servers. Choose a managed server and select the JNDI tree option. This will tell you who has taken the name.
You can also do this in you XML, specify JNDI as 
`<jndi-name>...</jndi-name>`
You can refer more about that here
[resource-description from Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13719/ejb_jar_ref.htm#i1445806)
The whole list of things tat can be mentioned in the ejb-jar.xml is mentioned here
[docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13719/ejb_jar_ref.htm#i1114706](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13719/ejb_jar_ref.htm#i1114706)

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer suggests me go to `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml` in `mytest` project and change `<local-jndi-name>TestEB</local-jndi-name>` to `<local-jndi-name>MyTestEB</local-jndi-name>` so the error is fixed.